# What is the protocol for a secure websocket?

Tags: nginx, go, mattermost

We've installed a Mattermost server and it works well.

We can only connect via http. Https gives an error.

The line of code that fails is

```
webSocketClient, err := model.NewWebSocketClient4("ws://mattermost.example.com", client.AuthToken)

make run
go run   *.go
Mattermost Bot Sample
Server detected and is running version 5.1.0
We failed to connect to the web socket
    Error Details:
        model.websocket_client.connect_fail.app_error
        model.websocket_client.connect_fail.app_error
        websocket: bad handshake
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x58 pc=0x13e1e55]
```

We opened up the http port 8065 and when we connect to port 8065, without ssl, it works.

```
webSocketClient, err := model.NewWebSocketClient4("ws://mattermost.example.com:8065", client.AuthToken)
```

What is the protocol for a secure websocket?

Comment: All-in-all, the error looks bad: as if someone did not check a connection actually succeeded and went on dereferencing a `nil` pointer.

Comment: It's not as bad as it looks :-) It's just a starter demo app. The demo was set up for HTTP and I had a requirement to get it working under HTTPS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normal websocket uses "ws://example.com"

Secure websocket uses "wss://example.com"

Note that some frameworks automatically handle this for you if you just leave off the ws: or wss: entirely.